# Force mapply to return a list?

Tags: r, mapply

Suppose I have a function that creates data frames.  I'd like to run that function with different input values, and then rbind the results together into one big data frame, as below:

```
CreateDataFrame <- function(type="A", n=10, n.true=8) {
  data.frame(success=c(rep(TRUE, n.true), rep(FALSE, n - n.true)), type=type)
}
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(toupper(letters[1:5]), CreateDataFrame))
```

My CreateDataFrame function takes three arguments.  In the example above, the second and third arguments are held constant.  I'd like to do the same as above, but have the second and third arguments change on each call.  I think I have to use mapply, like this:

```
mapply("CreateDataFrame", type=toupper(letters[1:5]), n=10, n.true=8:4)
```

I'm having trouble because mapply isn't returning a list, which prevents me from running `do.call(rbind, mapply(...))`.  How can I end up with a single data frame, as I did in the example at the top?

Looks like mapply is returning a matrix of lists.  I was expecting it to return a list of data frames.  What should I do differently?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get a list of data.frames as the return value, set `mapply`'s `SIMPLIFY` argument to `FALSE`. (Its default value is `TRUE`, which directs the function to "attempt to reduce the result to a vector, matrix or higher dimensional array" -- just what you experienced).

```
res <- mapply("CreateDataFrame", type=toupper(letters[1:5]), n=10, n.true=8:4, 
              SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

identical(class(res), "list")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you!  In retrospect, I should have read the manual more closely.

Comment: No problem. It took me quite a while before I learned that whenever I found myself thinking "wouldn't it be nice if function X did Y", there was a decent chance that the function's creator had beaten me to the thought!

Comment: it is so dumb that simplify needs to be in capital. Its form does not match sapply group functions

Answer (score 6):

Alternative you can use the Map function. It is basically mapply with SIMPLIFY set to FALSE.

```
Map("CreateDataFrame", type=toupper(letters[1:5]), n=10, n.true=8:4)
```

Comment: well how about that. Learn something new everyday

Comment: I didn't know that! So I looked up the code, and you're so right.

`> Map
function (f, ...) 
{
    f <- match.fun(f)
    mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}`