# Why does mapply not store ggplot objects in the output

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapply

When we use mapply in this scenario it will return the actual numbers that resulted from multiplying `x` and `y`:

```
mult.fun <- function(x, y) {
  x*y
}
res <- mapply(mult.fun, seq(1,3), seq(1,3)) # gives > 1 4 9
```

Then we can access the results later on using the list index:

```
res[[1]] # --> 1   (or just res[1])
```

I want to do exaclty the same however instead of numbers I want to store `ggplot2` objects:

```
plot.fun <- function(x, y) {
  ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
}
res <- mapply(plot.fun, seq(1,3), seq(1,3))
```

I thought this would simply store the results similar to the numbers, such that `res[[1]]` would give me a `ggplot2` object, but is returns this:

```
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "waiver"
```

When I call the function directly it will give me a `ggplot2` object:

```
class(plot.fun(1,1)) # --> "gg"     "ggplot"
```

How can I call the plot function and store the actual plots in a list? And why doesn't mapply do this?

Comment: `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`

Comment: use `Map` instead which has default `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`.

Comment: perhaps a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733650/force-mapply-to-return-a-list and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949372/r-mapply-ggplot-expr-must-be-a-length-1-vector

Comment: Thankyou, that was easy to fix... hahah @user20650

Comment: @CodeNoob ; cheers, I'll close this as a dup as the other answers provide the same solution